# Do I have to pay license costs for reading / manipulating PDF's on a server?

Tags: pdf, licensing, adobe

Do I have to pay license costs for reading / manipulating PDF's on a server to adobe?

Comment: Would you ask a lawyer a question about coding? Why are you asking programmers a legal question?

Comment: So, programmers are stupid coding robots with no other experiences or knowledge from other fields? If it was a funny bonmot, the smiley is missing...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not unless you use adobe software. [Pdf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdf) is an open standard and many open source libraries that create/read/manipulate pdf files exist.

Comment: PDF is a published ISO standard (ISO 32000-1).